# RSpec 2: Hash matcher with wildcards?

Tags: ruby, json, api, hash, rspec

I develop and plan to test a REST API against a set of predefined answers and of course, in the JSON responses of the server, things like URLs (with embedded IDs) will not match the (fixed) expectation strings.

Is there a rspec2 (we haven't migrated to rspec3 yet) matcher to compare a (multilevel) Hash containing Strings, Fixnums and more Hashes with a Hash containing Strings, Fixnums, *Regexps* (which can match multiple String and Fixnum objects) and more Hashes?

Example: I want this API response (in JSON),

```
response = { 
  id: 295180,
  url: "http://foo.bar/api/v1/foobars/295180",
  active: true,
  from: "2014-10-01T13:00:00+02:00",
  to: "2014-10-11T13:00:00+02:00",
  user: {
    id: 913049,
    url: "http://foo.bar/api/v1/users/913049",
    name: "john Doe",
    age: 29,
  }
}
```

to be matched by this comparator, which can (and should) be contained in a separate file (eg. matchers.json_re)

```
expectation = { 
  id: /\d+/,
  url: /http:\/\/foo\.bar\/api\/v1\/foobars\/\d+/,
  active: /(true|false)/,
  from: /2014-\d{2}-\d{2}T13:00:00+02:00/,
  to: /.*/,
  user: {
    id: /\d/+,
    url: /http:\/\/foo\.bar\/api\/v1\/users\/\d+/,
    name: "john Doe",
    age: 29,
  }
}
```

Something like

```
response.should == hash_re(expectation)
```

in rspec2.

Or is there a completely different approach regarding API response tests?

Comment: Just for clarification: Is this API server your Subject Under Test or a third party service?

Comment: Clarified above. Somehow this question reminds me of Rspec's "anything" parameter matcher which can be used in `should_receive` calls, like `@object.should_receive(:call).with(:foo, "bar", anything()).and_return(...)`.

Comment: where is hash_re coming from? never seen that

Comment: phoet, exactly that's why I want it. :) It's just an example of how I want to use the function (that doesn't exist yet).

Answer (score 2):

There isn'a a built-in matcher that will do what you want, however you could achieve it with a [custom matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-14/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher).  For a starter, this does some of what you want:

```
require 'rspec/expectations'

RSpec::Matchers.define :be_hash_matching_regexes do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    expected.all? do |key, regex|
      actual[key].to_s.match(regex)
    end
  end
end
```

Would then allow you to do:

```
response.should be_hash_matching_regexes(expectation)
```

This implementation doesn't do the deep matching you were after, but it should be fiarly straightforward to extend it to do that.